# Original sources of org.eclipse.jface_3.2.2

Tags: jface

I have google a lot and also download the Eclipse-Version 3.2.2 to get the source.

The plugin folder did'nt contain the sources.

Do somebody know where i can find/download them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try  JFACE FOR ECLIPSE PAGE

http://wiki.eclipse.org/JFace

Comment: Yeah i have read this but i didn't see that it contain the solution. Thanks.